# Alter column which is having date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I already have this query

```
alter table date_temp modify (dd_fld date);
```

**source**

```
dd_src
dt_fld
2015-11-04**
```

**target**

```
dd_temp
dd_fld
20151104
```

I have tried above query but i want to change the data as well my temp table with data having number help me out to find the query
example i have my source column dt_fld as date datetype
I have same temp table with column  df_fld as number and data has number 
find me out to alter column and data

Comment: you have a column that contain numeric data and you want to change them to date ?

Comment: See [**How to ask a good question**](http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html)

Comment: Also, none of your questions so far has an accepted answer, nor did you respond to the comments. I suggest you to go through [**Stack Overflow tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot **alter** the **data type** of a column which has **existing data**. You need to follow these steps:

- **Create** a new column as DATE data type
- **Update** the new column from existing column using **TO_DATE** and proper **format model**.
- **Drop** the existing column.
- **Rename** the new column to old column.

Comment: @anveshrao Please mark it as answered, would help others too!